# Expectation of the length of first part of a line

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables, expected-value

**Question**: 
a horizontal line of length 5  is divided into two parts first part is of length X find the expectation of X and also E[X(5-X)] .

**Source** :

> Fundamental of Mathematical statistics by SC GUPTA and VK kapoor

**My work** :

```
Let AB is a horizontal line. If C is any point on AB. 
Such that AC = a, 
so, the first part is a and second is (5-a) with probabilities a/5 and (5-a) /5.

 Let X is an event that length of first part be a. 

    X = 1 , x € FIRST PART 
       = 0 , x € SECOND PART. 

    E(X) = 1. a/5 + 0. (5-a) /5 
    E(X) = a/5 

    Similarly, 

    E(X^2) = a/5
    E[X(5-X)] = 5E(X) - E(X^2) 
                     = 4a/5.
```

*Correct me if I am wrong.*

Comment: You haven't specified a distribution so there's not enough information to calculate the expectation. Did you mean that the line is divided at a point uniformly randomly chosen along its length?

Comment: Yes it is divided by a point uniformly randomly chosen.

Comment: Please clarify the question accordingly. The question should be self-contained and not rely on the comments to be understood.

Comment: I found this question as it is above. I didn't change anything thing in it.

Comment: If you quote problems from elsewhere, please state the source.

Comment: Okay, I added the sources. Thanks !!